# CaffeonSpark build Error

Tags: caffe, protocol-buffers, caffe-on-spark

I am trying to get CaffeOnSpark running locally and I have compiled and ran caffe successfully, also I have installed opencv, but failed at compiling CaffeOnSpark.

The whole error stack when I make build is:

```
[INFO] 60 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] caffe .............................................. SUCCESS [  0.009 s]
[INFO] caffe-distri ....................................... FAILURE [ 16.940 s]
[INFO] caffe-grid ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.841 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-11T03:50:31+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/92M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (compile-generator) on project caffe-distri: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[9919,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[8280,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[5761,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[5238,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[16820,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[16649,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[12460,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[21447,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[21492,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[19484,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[19519,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[76524,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[76553,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[76744,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[74714,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[74733,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[74847,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[6716,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[17197,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[17622,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[17672,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[17352,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[17392,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[24932,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[25061,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[78929,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[79022,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[79946,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[18175,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[18324,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ProtocolStringList
[ERROR] location: package com.google.protobuf
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[5655,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable input_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[6395,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable input_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[6718,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable input_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[9429,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable testNet_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[11676,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable testNet_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[12462,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable testNet_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[16751,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable stage_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[17057,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable stage_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[17199,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable stage_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[17508,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable stage_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[17511,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable notStage_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[17938,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable stage_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[17943,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable notStage_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[18177,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable stage_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[18326,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable notStage_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[21274,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable bottom_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[21277,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable top_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[23940,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable bottom_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[23945,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable top_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[24934,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable bottom_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[25063,20] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable top_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[75951,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable bottom_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[75954,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable top_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[75975,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable param_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[78308,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable bottom_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[78313,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable top_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[78353,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable param_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[78931,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable bottom_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[79024,20] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable top_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/src/main/java/caffe/Caffe.java:[79948,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getUnmodifiableView()
[ERROR] location: variable param_ of type com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :caffe-distri
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Version of protobuf already in the system and that of in the caffe-distri/pom.xml file should be same. The entry in caffe-distri/pom.xml should look like this if you have protobuf of version 2.6.1

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there are still some errors: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) on project caffe-distri: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 2
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="/usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri" executable="make">... @ 5:96 in /usr/local/CaffeOnSpark-master/caffe-distri/target/antrun/build-make.xml

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Protobuf version issues. CaffeOnSpark works well with Protobuf 2.5. Please install protobuf V2.5 and try again. Version 2.6 does not work as of now.

Try these:

`wget https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v2.5.0/protobuf-2.5.0.zip 
unzip protobuf-2.5.0.zip
cd protobuf-2.5.0/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib
make
make check
sudo make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib`

Protobuf 2.5 will be installed by now. Check it using `protoc --version`.

Now go back to CaffeOnSpark folder and do `make clean` and then `make build`. It should work fine.